# Login Fail for IMAP on Exchange Server 2016

Tags: exchange, imap, pop3, exchange-2016

I have deployed Exchange Server 2016. I am able to send email over 587 while I face Login failure over IMAP 993 and POP3 995.

Over Microsoft Tool https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/ IMAP Test passes but using any other means (Java Mail or Scripts), I encounter Authentication failure over 993.

I am able to send mails with same script or Java Mail.

I have tried setting `LoginType` to all different modes.

```
DEBUG IMAPS: trying to connect to host "mail.xxx.com", port 993, isSSL true
* OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready.
A0 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=PLAIN SASL-IR UIDPLUS MOVE ID UNSELECT CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
A0 OK CAPABILITY completed.
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG IMAPS: protocolConnect login, host=mail.xxx.com, user=user1@xxx.com, password=<non-null>
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command result: A1 NO AUTHENTICATE failed.
DEBUG IMAPS: trying to connect to host "mail.xxx.com", port 993, isSSL true
* OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready.
A0 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=PLAIN SASL-IR UIDPLUS MOVE ID UNSELECT CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
A0 OK CAPABILITY completed.
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG IMAPS: protocolConnect login, host=mail.xxx.com, user=user1@xxx.com, password=<non-null>
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command result: A1 NO AUTHENTICATE failed.
SEVERE: Exception: AUTHENTICATE failed.
```

Comment: I have very similar problem. Were you able to fix your issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you configure LoginType as SecureLogin, it will use **secure port** (993 for IMAP4 and 995 for POP3) and an **Exchange certificate** with **POP3 or IMAP4** service.

Thus, check the certificate on your Exchange server, ensure it's enabled for POP3 and IMAP4 service.

Comment: Pop3 and IMAP4 are enabled. I have tried all 3 LoginType methods :)

Comment: Try to configure this account on Outlook (select manually configure it). Run "Get-IMAPSettings | FL" to list all settings.